# Encrypt the password in the database

Tags: php, mysql, hash, passwords

I am looking for a way to encrypt the password in the database.

I found a question similar to mine here: 
[How do I create and store md5 passwords in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6781931/how-do-i-create-and-store-md5-passwords-in-mysql)

But I didn't know what is the salt ? Do I need to added in my table beside user and password columns, and what data type should I give it ?

```
$escapedName = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']); # use whatever escaping function your db requires this is very important.
$escapedPW = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']);

# generate a random salt to use for this account
$salt = bin2hex(mcrypt_create_iv(32, MCRYPT_DEV_URANDOM));

$saltedPW =  $escapedPW . $salt;
$hashedPW = hash('sha256', $saltedPW);

$query = "insert into user (name, password, salt) values ('$escapedName', '$hashedPW', '$salt'); ";
```

Comment: Usually you don't store encrypted passwords, you hash passwords.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but I didn't know what is the salt ?

[The primary function of salts is to defend against dictionary attacks versus a list of password hashes and against pre-computed rainbow table attacks.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_%28cryptography%29)

> do I need to added in my table beside user and password columns

Yes it should be saved in your `users` table.
Because to check a password e.g. on log in you need encrypt typed password from a form input with the salt stored in the db for this user with the same algorithm:

```
$typedPW = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['password']); // from form input
$saltedPW =  $typedPW . $salt;  // $salt from db
$typedHashedPW = hash('sha256', $saltedPW); // compare it with db "password" value
```

and compare this computed string with stored one in `password` field (from your code) in db.

> what data type should I give it

it is an ordinary string